# Annual average temperature and precipitation data set (with data after 2016)

Tags: data-request, climate

I am wondering whether any of you knew of data sets for all countries with already calculated annual averages in temperature and precipitation levels? I am aware of all the different websites and databases that give all sorts of aggregated data, mostly daily and monthly.

However, I am rather looking at a ready-made data set as I am not an expert in any geospatial software.